# NSFormatter losing percision?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsnumberformatter, precision

I realize there have been other questions like this, but my problem does not seem to relate accurately. Here's the deal.

I have an app, that does a calculation. I am using floats for this. All floats work fine, and I convert the float value into a `NSNumber` for formatting.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter alloc];
    [numFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [numFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:1];
    [numFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:5];

    NSNumber *insulinRatio = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:insulinRatioCalc];
    NSLog(@"Original Number = %@", insulinRatio);
```

My `NSNumber`, insulinRatio, has accurate precision. However, when I convert that into an `NSString` with `NSNumberFormatter`, it loses all decimal precision.

```
NSString *numberAsString = [numFormatter stringFromNumber:insulinRatio];
    NSLog(@"Number = %@", numberAsString);
```

My output for these last logs where the following:

> 2013-01-08 16:12:27.944 MyApp[84062:c07] Original Number = 1.2
>   2013-01-08 16:12:27.944 MyApp[84062:c07] Number = 1

Why am I losing this precision. I know that `NSNumber` converts to double, but the `NSNumber` is fine here. It is the `NSNumberFormatter`. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just had to initialize NSNumberFormatter. #fail moment.

```
NSNumberFormatter *numFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc]init];
```

solved the problem. :)

Comment: Go ahead and accept you own answer so users can see that this question has been answered.

Comment: Exactly. If somebody wants to add a better answer explaining why this is the case and blah blah blah. Then I should accept that one. I don't think this answer should be closed as someone has voted for. This could still be helpful, even if the answer is quite obvious.